# in/at close quarters

Tags: idioms, prepositions

I've heard both 'in close quarters' and 'at close quarters', and I think they're generally interchangeable.

Is there any difference in meaning albeit subtle?

Comment: I have never heard "**in** close quarters." However, I have heard "In close combat."

Comment: You say " I think they're generally interchangeable." but this is not so. English has **very, very few** true synonyms - if a word differs from another, it will have a different nuance. ++ "**At** close quarters" tends to indicate the proximity of (usually) two opponents, e.g. on a battlefield. "**In** close quarters" tends to indicate "confined within a restricted area."

Comment: @Greybeard I think that might be the answer I'm looking for.